# query entity with linq passing in two parameters

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I had an ineffective way of returning a particular entity held in my table by using the following code:

```
     private static EntityModel.Name GetNameEntity(EntityModel.MultiIndexEntities context, int skipCount)
    {
        EntityModel.Name entity = context.Names
                                        .OrderBy(r => r.EntityId)
                                        .Skip(skipCount)
                                        .FirstOrDefault();

        return entity;
    }
```

Now, I'm wanting to refine this more. Each of the entities held in my table has a unique ID value and type value. What I'm wanting to do is re-write my method allowing me to pass in these values and return that entity.

I'm new to both linq and entity framework in general and this is my attmpt so far:

```
   private static EntityModel.Entity GetEntity(EntityModel.MultiIndexEntities context, int registrationTypeId, string name)
    {
        EntityModel.RegistrationType registrationType = context.RegistrationTypes
                                                           .Where(p => p.RegistrationTypeId == registrationTypeId)
                                                           .Where(p => p.Description == name);


        return registrationType;
    }
```

As I said, I don't know what I'm doing. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change as:

```
context.RegistrationTypes
       .Where(p => p.RegistrationTypeId == registrationTypeId && p.Description == name)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
context.RegistrationTypes
       .FirstOrDefault(p => p.RegistrationTypeId == registrationTypeId && p.Description == name);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `RegistrationTypeId` is the identity for the table, finding an entity with that just requires you to do

```
context.RegistrationTypes.Find(registrationTypeId);
```

If not, Farhad's code will do what you want, but from the look of what you're doing .. you should think about redesigning, as it looks like you might be overcomplicating things.